# android app development simple messaging app

Tags: android

I use the following `main.xml` code but I can only see one edit text box

I need help regarding why does this occur? I have tried many times but I cannot see proper edit box and all other components

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:text="ENTER THE PHONE NUMBER HERE" />

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/txtPhoneNo"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    />
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
    android:text="Message"
    />     
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/txtMessage"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:gravity="top"         
    />          
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnSendSMS"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send SMS"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you haven't set an orientation for your `LinearLayout` and the default is horizontal. Since you have all of your views width set to `fill_parent`, there is no room for the others

You have a couple options. You can either set

`android:orientation="vertical"`

in your root `LinearLayout` or you can change the width of these views

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

There are other ways too, obviously, but these are the easiest fixes for what you have

[LinearLayout Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html)

**Also Note**:

> FILL_PARENT (renamed MATCH_PARENT in API Level 8 and higher), which means that the view wants to be as big as its parent (minus padding)

[Layout Params](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html)

**Side Note**

I see you are using hard-coded strings in your xml. Eclipse will warn you about this and it may give you headaches in the future if you don't get accustomed to using the `strings.xml` folder and using the `android:text="@string/string_name"`

[Strings](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#String)

Comment: @user2072218 you are most welcome, glad I could help! Kindly accept the answer when you can so others can find it easier. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

On your LinearLayout check the orientation=vertical